# Axis Archive .aar deployment Issue

Tags: web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I have `.aar` deployed from `WEB-INF\services\ContainerBag.aar`

`ContainerBag.aar` contains only one file, that is `services.xml` and its content has a path to `webservice` location in its `service tag` section by `package` name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <defaults public="false" />
        <service id="parameter_bag" class="Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ContainerBag">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        </service>
</services>
</container>
```

There is another one file under `WEB-INF\services\`, that is`services.list`, that contains file name of the services,

```
ContainerBag
```

As it is a Maven project and as it is web project, those `webservice` class file and its package files are under `WEB-INF\classes` folder.

I am able to deploy the `webservice` as part of my `Weblogic` deployment successfully.

What I supposed to do in order to deploy this .aar file in Tomcat. As part of try I had already deployed `Axis2.war` in `Tomcat`, in order to invoke `services` in the project.

Comment: Did you try to put your aar file into [tomcat folder]/webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/services/   ?

Comment: Is there a relevance with `.aar` file building and `WSDL` generation with tool,- `wsdl2java` and conversion vice versa. As far as I know there are two `.class` files are involved from `Axis` framework for this `WSDL to java` and `java to WSDL`. Somehow the other folks who involved in the work on the same `VDI` butchered the way `stub` file gets generated and didn't try `Axis AAR` and `Axis MAR` plugin for `Apache Maven`. And still I hope the work is held up.

Comment: Moreover the try is to put it in `Tomcat` where there were lacks of `Context` which is been built by them so far, however there are few exists so far.